# Opencart admin section on another server

Tags: php, mysql, opencart, opencart2.x

Is there any way to have the admin area of open cart located on my own server and have it accessible from there while having everything else located on the client's server and using the same database (which would be located on the client's server as well)?

I know all the admin files are located in the admin folder it can't be as simple as just uploading those files to my server, is it? I'll be using Opencart 2.0.

Comment: sure, it is technically possible.  you would just to call the databases separately within the scripts

Comment: would you mean instead of using localhost you I would use the actual IP address of the remote server? Is that the only change needed? There must be more crossover than that.. what about the admin section where you select themes? I imagine it would throw errors since it would probably search a directory that doesn't exist on the local server.

Comment: You can't run it off of localhost if by that you mean your personal development server living on your computer (I really hope you don't mean that.  I'm assuming your development server is not live!)   However, if you mean your own *remote* server, you would just set up two database connections with different variables and call the one you need for which function.  It all depends on where you have which functions.

Comment: ideally, you would want everything on the client's server;  one less place for failure

Answer (score 0):

The theoretical answer to this is yes, you can.

You'll need to have the system folder on both servers since both the admin and catalog rely on the base classes to run.

On your client server you'll need:

```
catalog/*
config.php
crossdomain.xml
image/*
index.php
install/*
php.ini
system/*
```

On your admin server you'll want to make the normal admin folder your document root. So instead of `adminserver.com/admin` you'll just use `adminserver.com`

Admin server setup:

```
config.php
controller/*
index.php
language/*
model/*
view/*
php.ini
system/*
```

Then in your `adminserver/config.php` you would simply adjust you paths and db info as appropriate.

**But the "real world" answer to this in no, you can't.**

If you did do this, one of the main controllers in the admin area, `file manager` would not work.

File manager relies on the public images folder to upload images for your products. On a separate server the file manager would attempt to upload images to `image/data` which you could create on your `adminserver`, but obviously this wouldn't carry over to your client server.

You'd need to FTP your images to the client server with the exact same name and route as the admin server. Plus this could be extremely problematic for extensions. How would you set up modifications? Or extensions that have image parameters?

If maybe you had a CDN module in place, that might resolve the issue ... tough to say for sure.

Just keep in mind, once you've completed the install, you can change the `config` paths to whatever you like.

You don't have to use `admin` as your admin area, you can change it to `steve` or `aardvark` or whatever you like in the config file.

Having it on a separate server would be ideal, but for OpenCart, it's really not practical in a real world environment.